# How to handle this query in functional way?

Tags: java, functional-programming

//How can we handle the below code in functional way like collect all invalid sort params, prepare message with all them listed and finally throw InvalidSortParam exception.

DO you think the below query does it?

public Sort resolveArgument() {

```
    Sort sort = sortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument();

    List<Sort.Order> orders = sort.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> invalidSortList = orders.stream().map(Sort.Order::getProperty)
            .filter(property -> !allowedSortParams.contains(property))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (orders.isEmpty()) {
        sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, defaultSortParam);
    } else {
        if (orders.size() > sortMaxCount) {
            throw new InvalidSortException(INVALID_SIZE_PARAMS);
        } else {
            if (!invalidSortList.isEmpty()) {
                throw new InvalidSortException(invalidSortList.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + INVALID_SORT_PARAMS);
            }
        }
    }

    return sort;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you do not take advantage of the streaming functionality, you divided it into two separate steps - loading data, and when it is completed - transforming it. You could merge it into a single pipeline. Secondly - throwing exceptions is not a functional way. You should use some type to return a state e.g with some Try implementation.

```
final class Try<T> {

    private final Exception e;
    private final T t;

    public Try(Exception e) {
        this.e = e;
        t = null;
    }

    public Try(T t) {
        this.t = t;
        e = null;
    }

    public Exception getE() {
        return e;
    }

    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

and the code itself could look something like

```
public Try<Sort> resolveArgument()  {
    int cnt = getCount();
    return cnt == 0 ? Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, defaultSortParam) : someErrorHandlingLogic(cnt);

}

private static void getCount() {
    sort.stream().map(Sort.Order::getProperty)
            .filter(property -> !allowedSortParams.contains(property))
            .count();
}
```

If you're interested in the Functional Programming paradigm in java - I recommend great presentation https://dev.tube/video/YnzisJh-ZNI